# Use Hyperledger Fabric CLI for production?

Tags: command-line-interface, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

is it oke to use hyperledger Fabric CLI for production?

And another question, I know for a fact that cryptogen shouldn't be used for production, but what about the other tools? Like configtxgen? Fabric CLI? And so on..

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is while a client application can interact with Fabric blockchain network via both the Fabric SDK and Fabric CLI, the SDK provides a lot of functionality appropriate for use in production, whereas the CLI is meant more for development or maintenance work.

Normally a Production application would interact with Fabric network by way of connecting to REST API Server which would use a Fabric SDK as a library to communicate with the blockchain network. There are Node, Java and GO SDK Libraries available.

Comment: Thank you for your response!